# What is g() in snap SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Hey guys i was going through **[THIS](http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe)** snap.svg demo, Now when i check the code on my local machine , it looks like below:

```
        var g = Snap();
        g.attr({
            viewBox: [0, 0, 800, 600]
        });

        Snap.load("map.svg", function (f) {
            function getShift(dot) {
                return "t" + (400 - dot.x) + "," + (300 - dot.y);
            }
            var gr = f.select("g"),
                wrd = f.select("#world").attr({fill: "#fff"}),
                syd = f.select("#sydney").attr({fill: "red"}),
                msk = f.select("#san_francisco").attr({fill: "red"}),
                pth = f.select("#flight"),
                pln = f.select("#plane"),
                top = g.g();
            top.attr({
                mask: g.rect(100, 0, 600, 600).attr({
                    fill: "r(.5,.5,.25)#fff-#000"
                })
            });
```

I am just posting the initial part of the code that i am struggling to understand , in the above portion of the code there is the below line:

```
top = g.g();
```

Now of course looking at the snippet you can see that `g` is an instance of `snap()` but why the above line of code ?? The SVG i am dealing with is **[THIS](http://pastebin.com/95KM6azw)**.

I am not quite understanding the line of code `g.g()`. Can anybody explain ?

Comment: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.g

Comment: Yeah, looking at those docs - `g()` is a function that makes a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly their code is slightly confusing. First of all I would not do this, I'm a little surprised...

```
var g = Snap();
```

g normally means 'group'. However, Snap() does NOT return a group, it returns a Snap 'svg' element.

So instead I think they would normally do the following now which reads better...

```
var s = Snap()   // its an svg or snap instance
```

or

```
var paper = Snap() // its typically known as a paper you draw on
```

So then it would lead to this line instead, which 'looks' more correct when reading...

```
var top = paper.group() // you can use g and group interchangeably.
```

Which means add a 'group' container to the paper/svg element.